# how to prevent the browser back button after logout in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

Route,web.php

[image]

view page link to logout]

[image]

Comment: Please show effort in question creation.

Comment: Please paste code not image. Please read this
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: when you click back button the what happend ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't want to see previous page when you click on browser back button after the page already logged out even logout function destroys the session.

Here what I have in my laravel 5.4 to prevent user from coming back to previous page. Suppose I already have logout function.

File: /app/Exceptions/Handler.php

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception) {
   if (! $request->session()->has('logged_in')) {
       return redirect('your_login_page');
   }

   return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong.